# Dot Net Nuke app_offline randomly being generated

Tags: dotnetnuke, app-offline.htm

We have had multiple DNN sites running for quite a few months now without any issues.  Twice in the last 3 days our sites have gone offline by the addition of the app_offline.htm file in the root dir.

There is only one developer with access to the sites at a coding / directory viewing level and the file is generated at weird times times when he is NOT accessing our network.

We are not publishing anything to the server ( and have not published any .net code in days ), upgrading, changing code, or even modifying content.  Has anyone run into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like someone is messing with your server.  Can you view the event logs to see who is accessing your server?  Do you have the ability to change the passwords on the box?

Mark